# AWS Cloudwatch triggers Lambda function with a delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, expo, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm building an app for an online radio, with Expo and RN, where the users can get notified of the program that's currently airing.
I'm trying to use a AWS Lambda function connected with a DynamoDB db to dispatch the functions to the Expo Push Notifications service and am running that function in a 5 minutes interval with Cloudwatch.

Now, in the function, I send the notification and in the body of it, I add the current time and the currently playing title. Then, I have set up a Cloudwatch rule that triggers that function every 5 minutes. I expect to receive a notification afterward that contains the current information, the problem is that I get the time and playing title of 5 minutes BEFORE receiving the notification.

I doubt it's a traffic delay or something since I'm getting the notifications every 5 minutes consistently but with the information of 5 minutes before that. I've tried creating a new rule with the same results. I've tried manually adding the cron expression to the schedule but I still get the same result.

Here's the code that I have in the lambda function:

```
const https = require("https");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const { Expo } = require('expo-server-sdk');
let expo = new Expo();

AWS.config.update({region: "us-east-2"});

let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: "2012-08-10"});

let retrieveParams = {
  TableName: "playing",
  Key: {
    "curr": {N: "1"}
  },
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let dataString = '';
    let lastPlaying = "";
    let currPlaying = "";

    // Gets the latest played item
    ddb.getItem(retrieveParams, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        lastPlaying = data.Item.title.S;
      }
    });

    // Gets the currently playing title
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.get("http:serverurlsomethingsomething", function(res) {
          res.on('data', chunk => {
            dataString += chunk;
          });
          res.on('end', () => {
            resolve({
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.parse(dataString)
            });
          });
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject({
              statusCode: 500,
              body: 'Something went wrong!'
          });
        });
    });

    currPlaying = response.body.data[0].song;

    // Update the ddb if the current title has changed
    if (currPlaying !== lastPlaying) {
      // Updates the dynamoDB
      let newParams = {
        TableName: "playing",
        Item: {
          "curr": {N: "1"},
          "title": {S: currPlaying}
        }
      }; 

      ddb.putItem(newParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Success", data);
        };
      });


      // Create the messages that you want to send to clents
      let messages = [];
      let somePushTokens = ["MyPhonesToken"]
      for (let pushToken of somePushTokens) {
        // Each push token looks like ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

        // Check that all your push tokens appear to be valid Expo push tokens
        if (!Expo.isExpoPushToken(pushToken)) {
          console.error(`Push token ${pushToken} is not a valid Expo push token`);
          continue;
        }

        // Construct a message (see https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications)
        messages.push({
          to: pushToken,
          sound: 'default',
          body: `Minutes: ${new Date().getMinutes()} Seconds: ${new Date().getSeconds()} Title: ${currPlaying}`,
        })
      }

      let chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages);
      (async () => {
        // Send the chunks to the Expo push notification service. There are
        // different strategies you could use. A simple one is to send one chunk at a
        // time, which nicely spreads the load out over time:
        for (let chunk of chunks) {
          try {
            await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
      })();

      return "different";
    };

    return "same";
};
```

And here's how the Cloudwatch rule looks like:
[image]

So... any ideas what the issue may be? Am I missing something?

P.D. Yeah... I'll move the push notification logic to a separate file to keep the code cleaner.

Comment: For some reason, my greeting didn't appear...

Comment: So when lambda is executed at, e.g., 02:05 GMT, you get information which was supposed to be send at 02:00 GMT? Then when lambda is triggered at 02:10 GMT, you get information which was supposed to be send at 02:05 GMT?

Comment: Exactly that. I see it both in the time and airing title displayed in the notification.